# Is the semicolon in this sentence used correctly?

Tags: punctuation, adverbial-phrases, semicolons

I suspect that the semicolon in [this sentence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Tutorials/CycleTracker/Service_workers#debugging_service_workers:%7E:text=You%20likely%20want%20to%20test%20your%20edits%20in%20the%20browser%20regularly%3B%20likely%20with%20every%20save.) below seems wrong, because only two independent clauses can be stringed together by a semicolon. Adverbial phrases are not independent clauses.

> You likely want to test your edits in the browser regularly; likely with every save.

Perhaps it's a typo, and the author just intended to add a comma rather than a semicolon to improve the intonation?

Comment: I am inclined to agree. many people use a semicolon as a kind of supercharged comma, as here.

Comment: To clarify: don't do that!

Comment: Here is the University of Sussex style guide on the use of semicolons: https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/semi

Comment: U. of Sussex: 'don't get into the habit of using a semicolon (or anything else) merely to mark a breathing space. Your reader will be perfectly capable of doing his own breathing, providing your sentence is well punctuated; **punctuation is an aid to understanding, not to respiration**.'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That would seem to be a complete referenced answer  (hint)

Comment: Those occurrences of 'likely' are clumsy. I would prefer to replace the first with 'probably' and the second with 'ideally'. This poor style suggests an uneducated or lazy writer, or one more skilled in web design than English.

Comment: The sentence is very poor.

Comment: Note, I *have* seen semicolons recommended as a "supercharged comma" in a serial construction that is very long with complex phrases, like "The 18th century saw many fundamental changes in society: the rise of a stable, economically powerful middle class; the transfer of power from a consolidated monarchical seat to a more hierarchical regional system; and an emerging awareness across all strata of society of the so-called "rights of man," guaranteeing agency even to the lowest members." But I'd argue that sentences like these would be better broken up anyway.

Comment: Considering the position of semicolon on the keyboard, I believe this is a matter of typo

Comment: @Raestloz - yes. I don;t think it is an uncommon error.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your belief that a semicolon is used in error in this sentence:

> You likely want to test your edits in the browser regularly; likely
> with every save.

Better punctuation would be a colon (:) which serves to explain or elaborate upon what precedes it.

> The colon is used to indicate that what follows it is an explanation
> or elaboration of what precedes it. That is, having introduced some
> topic in more general terms, you can use a colon and go on to explain
> that same topic in more specific terms. Schematically:
>
> More general: more specific
>
> A colon is nearly always preceded by a complete sentence; what follows
> the colon may or may not be a complete sentence, and it may be a mere
> list or even a single word. A colon is not normally followed by a
> capital letter in British usage, though American usage often prefers
> to use a capital.

[The Colon (University of Sussex)](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/colon)

> The semicolon (;) has only one major use. It is used to join two
> complete sentences into a single written sentence when all of the
> following conditions are met:
>
> (1) The two sentences are felt to be too closely related to be
> separated by a full stop;
> (2) There is no connecting word which would
> require a comma, such as and or but;
> (3) The special conditions requiring a colon are absent.
>
> [...] observe carefully: the semicolon must be both
> preceded by a complete sentence and followed by a complete sentence.
> Do not use the semicolon otherwise:

[The Semicolon (University of Sussex)](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/semi)